# Rectangle is not drawn at its original coordinates

Tags: android, canvas, coordinates, touch-event, rectangles

I am facing problem while creating a CustomView which draw a Rectangle and can re-size by its corners.

Following is my code.

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    Canvas canvas;
    private Context mContext;
    private Rect rectObj;
    private Paint rectPaint;
    private Matrix transform;
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        initView();
    }
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        initView();
    }
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void initView() {
        rectPaint = new Paint();
        rectPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#55000000"));

        setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events
        canvas = new Canvas();
        // setting the start point for the balls

        rectObj = new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200);

        // Create a matrix to do rotation
        transform = new Matrix();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // This is an easy way to apply the same transformation (e.g.
        // rotation)
        // To the complete canvas.
        canvas.setMatrix(transform);

        // With the Canvas being rotated, we can simply draw
        // All our elements (Rect and Point)
        canvas.drawRect(rectObj, rectPaint);
    }
}
```

When I run this program, following output come.

[image]

As display in image, my "Rectangle"'s **top-left** are **100,100** but when I touch on "left-top corner of rectangle" on screen, **x-y** are **150,76** or something which are not match with original drawing.

I have to use **canvas.setMatrix(transform)** to rotate that rectangle in next phase.
Whats going wrong in this code?

Comment: the bottom left co-ordinate of your rectangle is 100 ie x i guess not the top left one. i am not sure but a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` one thing you should do is calling the method `super.onDraw(cavas)`, after that instead of doing 'canvas.setMatrix(transform);' you should do 'canvas.concat(transform);' because the canvas has an initial `Matrix` with some values saved. Also, if you just need to rotate or translate that rect, you can rotate and translate the canvas by doing `canvas.rotate(degree)` for example.

Comment: canvas.getMatrix().postConcat(transform); method not applying any changes made in "transform" matrix. I am doing "transform.setRotate(degrees, rectObj.exactCenterX(),rectObj.exactCenterY());". and after changes this, it is not rotating rectangle.

Comment: rotate the canvas instead of the matrix, `canvas.rotate(degrees, rectObj.exactCenterX(),rectObj.exactCenterY());`

Comment: but I want to then do something like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384186/calculate-new-positon-of-rectangle-corners-based-on-angle/384227?noredirect=1#384227.

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you want to do this, you can do canvas.concat().

Comment: once again you solve problem. But do you have any idea how can I change left-top and right-bottom corner's coordinates so that "handler" can be used to resize it again. Because, once I rotate that rectangle, corner points were at their old position so also after rotation it is not possible to re-size it again.

Comment: you can update the rect values, if that is what you are saying, I am not sure I understand what you need.

Comment: suppose my left top points are at 100,100 and I rotate that rectangle to 45 degree. So what happen rectangle will rotate due to matrix. But my points, which are used to take user touch events and re-size rectangle, are not changed. It must be some thing like 124,75 after rotation.